# How to get input file name as column in AWS Athena external tables

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, presto, amazon-athena

I have external tables created in AWS Athena to query S3 data, however, the location path has 1000+ files. So I need the corresponding filename of the record to be displayed as a column in the table.

```
select file_name , col1 from table where file_name = "test20170516"
```

In short, I need to know INPUT__FILE__NAME(hive) equivalent in AWS Athena Presto or any other ways to achieve the same.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can do this with the $path pseudo column.

```
select "$path" from table
```

Comment: Many thanks for the info.Please can you let me know any link pertaining to this as I was searching for a while and couldn't find any.

Comment: I found it a while back through the following github issue. https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/5486

Comment: Thanks Again. Are there any other pseudo columns like this that you are aware of?

Comment: See also answer from official AWS docs: "How can I see the Amazon S3 source file for a row in an Athena table": https://aws.amazon.com/en/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/find-s3-source-file-athena-table-row/

Comment: FYI, this works in presto-sql version 316 (and probably earlier).  So, it's a presto feature not just  an Athena feature.  Didn't know about it, but it's awesome to have - thanks!

Comment: Although one may not run into this complication often as partitioning should be used pretty much all the time, it's worth noting that the $path variable is not available in non-partitioned tables

Answer (score 28):

If you need just the filename, you can extract it with `regeexp_extract()`.

To use it in Athena on the `"$path"` you can do something like this:

```
SELECT regexp_extract("$path", '[^/]+$') AS filename from table;
```

If you need the filename without the extension, you can do:

```
SELECT regexp_extract("$path", '[ \w-]+?(?=\.)') AS filename_without_extension from table;
```

Here is the documentation on [Presto Regular Expression Functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html)

Comment: I was using split_part("$PATH",'/',7) to get the filename,yours is more generic though.Thanks.