# athena create table using python

Tags: python, pyathena

All:

On trying to create external table using pyathenajdbc with python, 
it had error as:

```
def create_tbl(self):
       #res = None
       full_s3_abs_path = self.check_files()
       conn_db = self.conn()
       #try:
       with conn_db.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(
             """CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s.%s (
                   ord_no              varchar(40),
                   ord_tmstp           varchar(32),
                   ord_hdr_mdfy_tmstp  varchar(32),
                   actn                varchar(32),
                   doc_type            varchar(20),
                   eod_bus_tmstp       varchar(32),
                   eod_msg             varchar(6),
                   entered_by          varchar(254),
                   entry_type          varchar(20),
                   max_ord_sts_desc    varchar(40),
                   min_ord_sts_desc    varchar(40),
                   mdfy_ts             varchar(32),
                   ord_cmplt_fl        varchar(6),
                   ord_purp            varchar(20),
                   ord_sts             varchar(100),
                   ord_hdr_key         varchar(40),
                   cre_user            varchar(40),
                   max_sts_tmstp       varchar(32),
                   grand_ttl           varchar(32),
                   grand_tax           varchar(32),
                   ln_sub_ttl          varchar(32),
                   str_no              varchar(32),
                   ord_src             varchar(32),
                   bp_id               varchar(40),
                   promo_id            varchar(38),
                   web_shper_id        varchar(32),
                   aff_info_site_tag   varchar(256),
                   aff_type            varchar(20),
                   aff_info_tm         varchar(32),
                   tax_exmpt_id        varchar(40)

            )
            ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\037'
            LOCATION '%s'
            TBLPROPERTIES (
              'skip.header.line.count'='1');""" % (self.sch_name, self.tbl_nm, full_s3_abs_path)
        )
            print "Athena Table %s Created Successfully" % (self.tbl_nm)
       #except:
       #    print "Unable to create DDL for athena table {}".format(self.tbl_nm)
       #    sys.exit(1)
       #finally:
       #  conn_db.close()
```

when creating an external table using pyathenajdbc driver in python 2.7, 
below is the error:

***"""...('skip.header.line.count'='1');""" % (self.sch_name,self.tbl_nm,full_s3_abs_path)
pyathenajdbc.error.DatabaseError: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to run query***

Comment: Im unable to get the exact issue , as when i create the same table in athena directly it is created successfully. Any help/advise would be great, as im still debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little trick to help when debugging DDL submitted through the CLI or through the SDK in Athena.  Try checking the logs in the console (see my reply on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081227/running-query-containing-pseudo-column-from-aws-athena-cli/48082235#48082235)), to see exactly what your code submitted to the Athena engine.